# Unity iOS pngcrush caught libpng error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, upgrade

I've updated xCode from 7.3.1 to 8.0 and my Unity project from 5.3.4 to 5.4.1, and when I try to build my project the same way it worked on previous versions, I get the following "Compress PNG Files error" 43 times:

```
While reading <path>/Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_full_open_on_phone.png pngcrush caught libpng error:


\253\231\244\240\206\243,\214\252\231\304\304S\324\370\225\206\2438\220\206\243\350\265\374\277x\265\374\277\252\221\255\231\244\240\206\243\370\225\206\243\211

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

I could not find any helpful information about this. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Programmer according to that answer, every plugin (*.jar files) in my plugins/android folder was already marked for android platform only. And, besides, it worked fine on the previous versions, why would it break in the newer one?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it worked for last version or not. This happens when you upgrade your project to another Unity version. It is a bug that has been known for a long time. I don;t think you followed that answer. It did not say only jar files. Check all .aar , .jar and .so files. Check in Android plugin folder and do that. Make sure to apply changes. Try to switch platform to iOS while doing this. The error **"While reading <path>/Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib"** says it all. It is reading files from /Plugins/Android as iOS plugin....

Comment: @Programmer I decided that there are too many files to check(I have several android plugins), so I just deleted the Android folder since I do not need it in iOS, and it worked. Thanks a lot for giving me a tip.

Comment: You are welcome... You know something is wrong when you see xcode reading /Plugins/Android directory. Happy coding!